# Is a university instructor required to mention whether they allow late work in their course?

Tags: university

Does a instructor have to specify whether or not they accept late assignments? Only now, after three years of college, have I encountered a professor who does not explicitly state his policy for late assignments. Neither on the course outline nor in person. I would like to know if it is strongly suggested that professors set a policy on late assignments. Moreover, does the lack of a late work policy subject the instructor to the risk of students claiming ignorance?

Comment: Have you asked your instructor whether they have a policy, yet? Also: I'm not sure what "student reprisal" is intended to mean, and perhaps the word "reprisal" isn't what is meant. It frankly sounds violent.

Comment: @Anonymous M Edited, thanks. Also, there hasn't been a response in about 3 weeks via email. I and a few students have emailed him twice using his preferred contact.

Comment: A deadline seems like a pretty explicit policy to me.

Comment: I do not tolerate late submissions. If a deadline is mentioned, assume it is final. Most students don't realize that real life is even harsher than university. If you miss a deadline on your job you won't get away with it. Train for that and respect deadlines even if you need to submit incomplete work.

Comment: Having a late policy can make the deadline pointless depending on what it is. It doesn't stop you from asking for an extension on an assignment *ahead of time* though.

Comment: @BeniBogosel What I have actually found in real life is that there is a great deal of variation -- NSF submission deadlines are absolutely firm, the IRS will give you a six month extension with no questions asked, I probably shouldn't say what you can get away with as a referee for journals. Students absolutely should learn to manage deadlines, but there is also an aspect of college socialization in learning which deadlines aren't firm and how to appropriately ask for extensions.

Comment: Note that if instructor uses Moodle (or something similar) and sets due date there, students simply cannot submit their work late. In that case it would make no difference if you try submitting homework 5 minutes late or not making it at all - you didn't submit anything.

Comment: @BeniBogosel, in addition to what David there said, in some places those unyielding deadlines mean the student has to take the the course (or relevant parts of it) again the next year. That's hardly how it works in the real world: a client isn't going to ask for the same thing again next year just because your company couldn't deliver at the agreed time. Rather, they'd be be more likely to complain, ask for penalties, or find a new supplier.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Don't you still need to *request* the extension from the IRS? (In any case, the extension is for *filing*, not paying.)

Comment: @BeniBogosel As someone who has worked on many projects in which intermediate deadlines flew past in a blur of Burma shave signs, I'd disagree.  Artificial deadlines are common in the "real world" and often can be ignored with a bit of elbow grease and explanation.  The difference is, of course, that the work product the student produces for the professor has zero use to the professor, so discarding late work product has no cost; in the real world, late work product is often (not always) 90%+ as good as on-time work product, and discarding it would be stupid.  Sometimes, deadlines are real tho

Comment: @ZizyArcher That's not true. Canvas can be configured to accept submissions after the deadline.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yeah, that is probably also possible if you set it like that. But in all cases where I saw due date set in the system, it was the fixed due date when submission closes, unless student asks instructor to reopen submission. So I commented from that perspective - that late submission perhaps simply isn't possible.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Yes, it is possible to configure these multiple ways. Just saying "simply cannot submit their work late" is not a universal truth about LMSes.

Comment: @beni “Most students don't realize that real life is even harsher than university.” Like the other commenters, I find this to be rarely true. In my view, overly aggressive deadline enforcement in school is needlessly cruel, degrades trust (because students can tell when deadlines are abitrary), and often requires un-learning when students arrive in the workforce.

Comment: I must say I am surprised to see so many opposed to ferm deadlines. I'm not sure what message you want to send to students by allowing late submissions. Deadlines are not always artificial. Professors also need to submit grades up to a certain date. Homework for the current week should not interfere with the work for the next one, etc. Anyways, I spoke my mind and I would prefer a world where deadlines were respected not pushed back by many.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Does a instructor have to specify whether or not they accept late assignments?

No. If an assignment is described as being due by a certain date, then In the absence of any statements to the contrary, you should assume that will not be accepted after the due date. That’s basically implicit in the meaning of “due” and does not need to be stated explicitly, unless the university has a policy requiring this.

> does the lack of a late work policy subject the instructor to the risk of students claiming ignorance?

Perhaps, but I doubt that’s something the professor is worried about, or that claiming ignorance would get you anywhere.

Comment: To your last point, if a student claimed ignorance trying to argue that "due date" doesn't mean the date something is...due, then they learned something new :)

Answer (score 6):

In the UK, this would generally be a decision made at the University or programme level, rather than by individual instructors. There would generally be a duty to publicize the policy, but only via a webpage or student handbook, and again not applying to instructors. To pick an example (found by Googling regulations for a couple of likely institutions) Bristol University has [a regulation](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/academic-quality/assessment/regulations-and-code-of-practice-for-taught-programmes/penalties/)

> 17.3   Students must be made aware of the existence of penalties for not meeting submission deadlines in the relevant school or faculty handbook.

The following regulations describe the actual penalty itself.

Comment: There is typically a procedure by which exceptions can be made, which varies in the means and difficulty to apply for it.  For example, if the student were to have an accident and end up in a coma on the way to submitting their project, maybe their supervisor could apply to the Head of Department for an extension.  That is typically mentioned in the rules (eg in the above Section 19 covers extenuating circumstances).  In general a student should not assume they have an exception unless one is applied for.

Comment: Note (although this is clearly an individual case) that this example only mentions *penalties*, rather than simply not accepting work submitted late.

Comment: @preferred_anon I’m not going to say no UK university has a “no late coursework” rule (academia is wide and varied, even in one country), but I’m not aware of any. On the other hand some rules are very close to it (e.g. up to 24h late is capped at the pass mark, any later capped at zero). The important part is that lecturers only remind students as a courtesy, and ignorance of the content of their handbook is no defence on appeal.

Comment: @preferred_anon In the US, "late work receives a 0" is a perfectly valid penalty for late work. (Generally that includes some broad exception for extreme emergencies...although what a professor judges an extreme emergency and what a student judges an extreme emergency is of course a point of contention--but also professors have increasingly moved to online submission open any time up to a specific date and encouraging submission before the very last minute so things like "my car broke down" or "my internet was out" are increasingly irrelevant.)